# is there any way to get a specific field's value from a table?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I am trying to create a table containing a set of data about different users,
where each row contains details about a specific user who are waiting for admin's approval.So, what i want is that after clicking on approve button of one of the row resembling a specific user's data,it should be directed to new window with user details where i can make use of those details for further processing for that specific user.

I have tried using form tag on "tr" tag,also i tried using form id within
 "td" tag.
I have also tried using "tbody" tag and applied onclick() event on it to get specific row data,but this thing is only works for first row.

```
 userData is an object containing all the data of different users retrieved from database.
```

```html
<table align="center" cellspacing="20" id="data">
    <% include ./partials/messages %>

    <tr class="columns">
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Designation</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Approve</th>

      <% for(var i in userData.fname){%>
      <% if(userData.approve[i] == false && userData.reject[i] == false){ %>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td class="ralign"><%= userData.fname[i] %></td>
      <td class="ralign"><%= userData.lname[i] %></td>
      <td class="ralign"><%= userData.email[i] %></td>
      <td class="ralign"><%= userData.designation[i] %></td>
      <td class="ralign"><%= userData.contact[i] %></td>
      <td class="ralign"><button onclick="">Approve</button></td>

    </tr>

    <%}%>
    <%}%>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: you can use anchor `<a href="your_url/user_id">Approve</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do above , suppose you need to pass `name` of user,so you can do like below :

```
<td><a href="yourpage.jsp?name=<%=userData.fname[i] %>"> <input type="Button" value="Approve"/> </a></td>
```

and to get above `name` you can write like below :

```
 String name=request.getParameter("name");//will give you name which is pass in url
```